# Using a charger backwards

Tags: diodes, transformer, ac, dc, charger

I was wondering if connecting a 5 volt source to a 5 volt charger is going to yield 220 volts at the plugging terminals(the charger is AC/DC,220 volts input and 5 volts output)As far as I know,every charger has a transformer inside and a primary coil induces AC into a secondary coil,then the current is transformed into DC by some diodes.Now if I wanted to transform DC into AC I won't be sucessful because DC currrent won't induce anything in the primary coil from the second coil,isn't that right?Can I use a AC/DC charger to obtain AC from DC?

Comment: Disregarding switching supplies, you can't run a rectifier "backwards" to get AC from DC. What you need is called an [inverter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_inverter).

Comment: It would be possible to create a charger that worked this way (unlike Olin's self-filling gas tank) but in practice it's never done. (Proof-of-existence : a reversible motor-generator could be made to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can a 220V AC to 5V DC converter be 'reversed' by connecting 5V DC to its output to get 220V AC out?

Answer: No.

Electronics circuits are usually too complex to support 'reversing' and getting a reversed result.

So even though some components have 'reversible' effects (in this case their may be a transformer), the overall reversed effect may be destroyed by one part of the circuit. For your example the diodes will significantly effect the invertible/reversible action of a transformer. They aren't symmetric, if you apply DC to one side, they won't generate AC on the other.

So yes, your analysis "*DC current won't induce anything in the primary coil from the second coil*" is correct. (Though it might not be so clear cut.)

However, it is worse than that, because many power supplies are more complex than  transformer, for example a Switched Mode Power Supply. There the circuit is even more 'asymmetric' in behaviour.

Edit:
An examples of another very simple, none reversible circuit, is a voltage divider, composed of two resistors.

The junction of the two resistors is at a voltage (PD) between the outer voltage (PD) (say ground and 12V), but applying a voltage (PD) across one resistor will *not* create a larger voltage across the resistor combination.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work that way.

You can't coast a car with the engine engaged but off and get more gasoline into the tank either.

Comment: Points for the humorous answer